# Como fazer sliders criados com bootstrap, ficarem responsivos em todos tamanhos de tela?

Tags: html5, css3, layout-responsivo

O banner do meu site esta rodando bem em monitor de até 15 polegadas.
De resoluções acima destas os banners ficam muito grandes e geram barra horizontal no site.
Como na imagem a seguir:
[![https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwK2Z.jpg][1]][1]

Segue o código

html:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner slides">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/slider1.jpg" class="d-block w-100 slides" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Criação de Sites</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="img/slider2.jpg" class="d-block w-100 slides" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Design para Web</h3>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/slider3.jpg" class="d-block w-100 slides" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Redes Sociais</h3>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span>
  </a>
</div> 


css:


body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 75px;
}


.slides {
    width: 100vw;
}

#carouselExampleIndicators {
    max-width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Aqui esse código funcionou normal sem a barra de rolagem!

Comment: qual a resolução e polegadas do seu monitor?
em monitores grandes por site de teste aparece com barra horizontal
http://whatismyscreenresolution.net/multi-screen-test?site-url=https://mdwebdesign.tk/teste.html&w=1920&h=1200
porém pelo console do google chrome aparece normal em todas resoluções, 
Já nestes sites de teste de resolução, quando o monitor é maior que 15 polegadas sempre aparece barra horizontal

Comment: Olha ai como está aqui, sem barra Horizontal https://imgur.com/jsknuHe vc tem o link do site que está com o problema?

Comment: Sim o link é https://mdwebdesign.tk/

Comment: Cara seu problema é que vc colocou o Carrossel dentro de um Container com um Row dentro.... Na verdade nesse caso o carrossel não deve ficar "envolto" pela tag do container ou row. O Caroucel deve estar fora dessas tags, direto no body, Ou então tire a classe `container-fluid` da section, e a classe `row` da div de fora do Carrossel. Se der certo me fala que posto como resposta

Comment: neste link https://mdwebdesign.tk/teste.html já esta sem estas tags e mesmo assim nos sites de testar resolução aparece a barra horizontal nas resoluções grandes 
http://whatismyscreenresolution.net/multi-screen-test?site-url=https://mdwebdesign.tk/teste.html&w=1920&h=1200

Comment: Cara aqui para mim a tela não tem esse scroll http://prntscr.com/noly77

Comment: acredito que depois de colocar overflow-x: hidden no body esta tudo funcionando bem.
Mesmo alguns sites de teste de resoluções aparecendo barra horizontal, 
Pelo console do chrome não aparece a barra e um colega meu testou no monitor de 21 polegadas dele e não apareceu barra depois de eu colocar overflow-x: hidden no css do body
Acho que o erro agora é destes sites de teste de resolução e não do site em si, acredito que esteja rodando bem em todas resoluções
Obrigado

Comment: Sim Matheus o problema pode ser com esses sites, eles não são muito confiáveis, testei em varias resoluções e nada da barra, e quando eu testei eu tirei o overflow do body e mesmo assim não apareceu a barra. Se não for problema pra vc posso postar como resposta para vc aceita-la ✔, assim a pergunta não fica em aberto mesmo já tendo sido resolvido.

Comment: Ok Obrigado vou fazer isto, só me ajuda por favor, porque aparece no console do chrome porcentagem nas resoluções, ai quando coloco em 100% se esta em 1920 x 1200, a resolucao vai para 1399 x 595

Comment: Cara deixei a resposta pra vc. Sobre esse problema com Dev Tools eu não sei dizer pq o seu está assim, talvez se o seu monitor for de alta densidade tipo Retina, pode apresentar esse comportamento, no mais deveria ser possível de ajustar o manho da janela arrastando por aqui ou digitando o número http://prntscr.com/npjs5a

Comment: Ok Hugo Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme resolvido no comentário seu problema é que vc colocou o Carrossel dentro de um `Container` com um `Row` dentro.... Na verdade nesse caso o carrossel não deve ficar "envolto" pela tag do `container` ou `row`. O Caroucel deve estar fora dessas tags, direto no `body`, Ou então tire a classe `container-fluid` da section, e a classe `row` da `div` de fora do Carrossel.

Tano o `.container` quanto o `.row`, possuem `margind` e `paddings` que se somam ao slider causando esse problema do `scroll` horizontal, pois isso vc deve deixar o carrossel fora dessas tags, pare que ele ocupe 100% da largura da tela, mas sem somar `padding` ou `margin` neles.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]